# T4 namespace and type resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, t4

I'm trying to create T4 template that will take my app global Resources, loop through the static properties and create a static class with `const string` properties, so I would be able to get resource names as `string` by using the strong type.

Here's what I have now:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#  CodeGenerationTools code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
    MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
    CodeRegion region = new CodeRegion(this, 1);
    MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);
    string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceName))
{ #>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(namespaceName)#>
{
<#    PushIndent(CodeRegion.GetIndent(1));
} #>
    public static class ResourceStrings {
<#      var props = typeof(Resources).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var prop in props) { #>
            public const string <#= prop.Name #> = "<#= prop.Name #>";
<#      } #>
    }
<# if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceName))
{
    PopIndent(); #>
}
<# } #>
<#+
  // Insert any template procedures here
#>
```

The problem is that it just can't find the `Resources` namespace in the `typeof()`. The `Resources` namespace is the namespace of my Localize.designer.cs file (autogenerated file of Localize.resx).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had a similar idea. I wanted to have a static class with const string values for my user settings in order to use a strong type rather than a string in Windows Forms Binding:

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Properties.Settings.Default, Properties.Settings.PropertyNames.SomeStringValue);
```

However, I figured out that a t4 template cannot access the types of the current project.
You have to load the file with

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>
```

However, if you do that and regenerate your template you not rebuild your project since the file is in use unless you close visual studio.

Long story short,

I dropped this approach and now I read the app.config file by myself to get the data I need.
Should be quite easy to modify to read the `Resources.xml` file instead.

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>

<#
var xmlFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile), "..", "app.config");
var query = from x in XElement.Load(xmlFile).Element("userSettings").Element("Your.Namespace.Properties.Settings").Elements("setting")
            select x;
#>

namespace Your.Namespace.Properties
{
    public sealed partial class Settings
    {
        public static class PropertyNames
        {

        <# foreach (var item in query) { #>
        public static readonly string <#=item.Attribute("name").Value#> = @"<#=item.Attribute("name").Value#>";
        <# } #>

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a great idea, thanks. I actually found the reference to ResxResourceReader class which is in the System.Windows.Forms namespace but had some issues with it inside MVC app, so I switched to this, reading the data elements from the RESX file and it works perfectly.

Comment: Just a quick note that the issue with the file being locked in use is fixed in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 for those able to use that.

Comment: @GarethJ: Good to know, thanks. But I also understand it is dangerous to access the same assembly from within a T4 template (Let's say I just did a cleanup and run my template. Template complains about the assembly missing so I have to recompile which won't work because my template is broken and the generated code I referenced is missing, I am much more comforable with this solution ;)

Comment: Agreed - I like the code approach much better too, even across closely related asemblies - I hate it when code gen is broken because the app doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

You can grab a reference to the current namespace using the following:

```
<#+
    // other template code here...
    static string CurrentNamespace = System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.LogicalGetData("NamespaceHint").ToString();
```

And use it in your template output like so:

```
namespace <#=CurrentNamespace #>
{
    public static class MyGenerateClass
    {
       // other generated code here...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the T4Toolbox and the Volatile Assembly directive.

```
<#@ VolatileAssembly processor="T4Toolbox.VolatileAssemblyProcessor"
Name="<Your assembly fully qualified name that you are concerned about locking but need a self reference to>"#>
```

It will create a shadow copy of the assembly for use for T4.

You need to download and install the T4Toolbox for this to work.

http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/